# there is 404 error with axios(react) and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

this is my react code

```
 <button type='submit' onClick={()=>{axios.get('https://eccwithnodejs.df.r.appspot.com:443/user').then((res)=>{console.log(res.data)}).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
    });}} >버튼</button>
```

and these are my node js code with express

**this is create server code**

```
    var server=http.createServer(app).listen(8080,function(){
        console.log('succesful');
    })
    
    https.createServer(options,app).listen(443,function(){
        console.log('succesful https');
    })
```

**this is get method**

```
app.get('https://eccwithnodejs.df.r.appspot.com:443/user',function(req,res){
var tempUser={"name":"asd",
"birth":970204,
"email":"으헤헤헤이거슨이메일",
"uid":"유니크다음은 전설"
}

res.send(tempUser);
console.log(tempUser);
})
```

and I got errorcode 404 like this

```
{data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…ody>\n<pre>Cannot GET /user</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

What is the problem? please help... :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your get method, you also need to mention the endpoint not full domain name. So, remove your domain name from the get method.

```
app.get(/user',function(req,res){
var tempUser={"name":"asd",
"birth":970204,
"email":"으헤헤헤이거슨이메일",
"uid":"유니크다음은 전설"
}
```

now change your react code.

```
<button type='submit' onClick={()=>{axios.get('https://<<your_domain>>:8080/user').then((res)=>{console.log(res.data)}).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
    });}} >버튼</button>
```